# ASP.NET Core app with Azure AD authentication behind a reverse proxy is setting the wrong redirect_uri

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-application-gateway

I've been banging my head on this for a while.
I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app running on an Azure App Service.  The web app has Azure AD authentication setup, with forwarded headers.
Here's the `ConfigureService`:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    });
```

And here's the `Configure`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(Configuration["AllowedHosts"]);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I'm using an Azure Application Gateway as a reverse proxy.  **Problem occurs in the authentication flow.  Once authenticated, the redirect_uri provided in the URL is the `*.azurewebsites.net` address and not the one I configured in the App Gateway `*.mydomain.com`**.  Further investigation  reveals the following headers are provided to the App Service in a request:

```
X-FORWARDED-PROTO: https
X-FORWARDED-PORT: 443
X-Forwarded-For: ***IP ADDR OF APP GATEWAY***
X-Original-URL: ***
X-ORIGINAL-HOST: *.mydomain.com
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 5|CN=*.azurewebsites.net
X-AppService-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-TlsVersion: 1.2
```

What else do I need to tell my backend app to use the forwarded headers (in my case, X-ORIGINAL-HOST seems to be the only one containing the actual requesting host)?
This seems like a pretty straight forward use case.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you set Custom Domain in your App Service also?

Comment: @Ricardo no.  Doesn't make much sense in my head to set the custom domain on the app service when it's supposed to be handled by the gateway.

Comment: It's not necessarily related to Azure. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTTP Settings under Hostname settings, mention *.domain.com. If youmake that change, make sure you have configured the Backend with the custom domain.

Regards,
Msrini

Comment: When I tried setting my custom domain in the HTTP setting, I get a 502 bad gateway.
What do you mean by configuring the backend with the custom domain?
thanks

Comment: In your App Service, you have an option called custom domain. You need to configure that so that you can use the same FQDN in the Application Gateway HTTPSettings

Comment: well it seems to have worked when the app service has the custom domain and SSL certificate attached. I Still find it counter-intuitive to have to setup the certificate in both the App Gateway and App Service.

Comment: If Application Gateway is configured with end to end SSL, then you need to setup cert in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. Make sure to include `XForwardedHost` in your options configuration, or just include `ForwardedHeaders.All` like this:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
});
```